# np.nan appears black in 3d numpy array - imshow plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I have a 3d numpy array of shape `(6209, 2464, 3)` with `dtype=float32` Each dimnension is an RGB channel and the image contains `np.nan`. If I plot one channel only, with the following code, the image looks good since the `np.nan` pixels are plotted as white.

> `plt.imshow(img[:,:,0])`

[image]

However, if I try to plot the three channels at the same time, with the following code, the pixels that are `np.nan` appear black now.

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

Why is that happening? I need the `np.nan` pixels to be white when plotting the three channels together. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try this bit of code

```
import math

your_array = [CHOOSEN NUMBER if math.isnan(x) else x for x in your_array]
```

if I am not wrong will change your NaN in the array to CHOOSEN NUMBER. I don't know what are the numbers inside your array (apart of being float32) and I don't know how matplotlib pyplot converts them in an image, but could be that treats NaN differently when dealing with RGB or grayscale arrays. With a sample of your array we could test it.

So choose your CHOOSEN NUMBER wisely and see what happens

got problem reproducing your issues, its a big array. Nevertheless tried with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jun 13 15:21:50 2021

@author: Pietro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67958512/np-nan-appears-black-in-3d-numpy-array-imshow-plot/67958683#67958683

"""

# import matplotlib as plt

import math

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


arrayz = np.array(np.random.rand(50,50,3), dtype=np.float32)


print(type(arrayz), arrayz.size, arrayz.shape)


# for i in range(arrayz.shape[0]):
#     for j in range(arrayz.shape[1]):
#         print(arrayz[i,j])
#         for o in arrayz[i,j]:
#             print(type(o))

plt.imshow(arrayz) 
plt.show()

input("Press Enter to continue...")

plt.close()


arrayz[:] = np.NAN      ## CONVERTS ENTIRE ARRAY TO NaN
# for i in range(arrayz.shape[0]):
#     for j in range(arrayz.shape[1]):
#         print(arrayz[i,j])
#         for o in arrayz[i,j]:
#             print(type(o))


print(type(arrayz[0,0,0]), arrayz[0,0,0])
plt.imshow(arrayz[:,:,0]) 
plt.show()

input("Press Enter to continue...")

plt.close()

######## convert NaN to number ######################
for i in range(arrayz.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arrayz.shape[1]):
        for o in range(arrayz.shape[2]):
            print(arrayz[i,j,o])
            if math.isnan(arrayz[i,j,o]):
                arrayz[i,j,o] = 255    ### -----> here put 255 if you use 0 plot gets black
             
            else:
                pass

# plt.imshow(arrayz[:,:,:]) ##--> same as below
plt.imshow(arrayz) 
plt.show()
```

and pyplot seems to behaves exactly like your problem, the the RGB plot image here: [image: enter image here] and the converted to nan array[:,:,0] here: [image]

The last plot is white( not showed) only if :

```
for i in range(arrayz.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arrayz.shape[1]):
        for o in range(arrayz.shape[2]):
            print(arrayz[i,j,o])
            if math.isnan(arrayz[i,j,o]):
                arrayz[i,j,o] = 255    ### -----> here put 255 if you use 0 
plot gets black
```

so it seems to me behaviour is related to how pyplotv treats NaN in RGB or 1D-array/images

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also suspect that the `np.nan` are been treated as somehting else when ploting the rgb. The values in the array go from `np.nanmin= 0.015686277`  to `np.nanmax = 1.0`